# Fundamentally, why are the execution contexts of function declarations' 'this' binding set to the global object?

Tags: javascript

Can't seem to grok this.

My attempt reasoning toward an explanation:

A function declaration (like var declarations) is bound to the global Object Environmental Record (OER).

The global OER is synced with the global object.

The global object has the function as a property.

Thus the function is called implicitly through globalObj.function (and the call determines the 'this')

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-environment-records

Answer (score 2):

No, this has nothing to do with function being a "property" of the global object (although historically, it might have been the inspiration, I don't know).

The `this` value in a function is set in the [*OrdinaryCallBindThis* procedure](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis) during a function call, and the behaviour you refer to depends on strict mode. In sloppy mode, if the *ThisArgument* is `undefined` or `null` (which is the case for an ordinary `someFunction()` call), it will use the global object (or more accurately, the *GlobalThisValue*).

Comment: From your link, in non-strict mode with no 'this' arg: "Let thisValue be globalEnvRec.[[GlobalThisValue]].", and it seems [[GlobalThisValue]] is determined by: "The value returned by this in global scope. Hosts may provide any ECMAScript Object value." according to: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#table-18.

Comment: Is it really that arbitrary or am I missing something?

Comment: @AskP Yes, it's more or less arbitrary, I think it got that complicated because in browsers, `window` is not exactly the global object. See e.g. [this explanation](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global#html-and-the-windowproxy) for the minuscule (but largely unimportant for your question) differences.